# I encountered a TypeError: cannot read properties of null(reading 'python'), when I'm trying to create a new project in Rstudio of MacOS

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, new-project

Recently, I bought a MacBook Air m1 and started to write my code in Rstudio.

These are my installed files.
R: R 4.2.1 GUI 1.79 Big Sur ARM build;
Rstudio: RStudio-2022.11.0-daily-120.dmg;

The problem I encounter is as the following:

[when I create a new project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqEUr.png)

Main purpose: create normally a new project in Rstudio of MacOS.

Comment: What is the version of `python`?

Comment: how do I know the python version? Why I ask this is because I haven't downloading python on my Mac. :<

Comment: You have to install python in your machine , you can use [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) to get all you want.

Comment: oh! it's worked! nothing change until I use anaconda. Thank you so much! :)